# onblur executes wrong

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onblur

I am making a validation of a HTML form with JavaScript.
Why does `Validator.validateInput` execute when I refresh page?

I want it to execute when I blur the element "**first**".

```
var Validator = {
init: function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var first = form.elements[0];
        first.focus();
        var firstname = /^[a-z -']+$/;
        first.onblur = Validator.validateInput(first,firstname);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
first.onblur = Validator.validateInput(first,firstname);
```

What this line is doing is calling `Validator.validateInput` with two parameters (`first` and `firstname`).  Then it's setting `first.onblur` to the return value of `validateInput`.

So, `Validator.validateInput` is executing when the page loads, because that's what you're doing.  You probably want to do it like this:

```
first.onblur = function(){
    Validator.validateInput(first,firstname);
};
```